# Preventing key events

Tags: c++, qt, events

I have a simple application with just one QPlainTextEdit, basically the same as Qt's example here:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/mainwindows-application.html

When I press Ctrl+Z, it calls undo. When I press Ctrl+A, it selects all text. This is ok.

But when I press Ctrl+E or Ctrl+R, which are not defined in the menu, the characters "e" and "r" will appear in the QSimpleTextEdit.

How do I prevent this? How to "filter" keypresses which have been defined as menu shortcuts and keep them working, and "prevent" those keypresses not defined as menu shortcuts from appearing in the edit?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options:

1) Create a subclass and reimplement `keyPressEvent()`

2) Create an eventFilter and use `installEventFilter()` (see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#installEventFilter)

Comment: Could you be please more specific? In particular, going with the first option, do I have to check each off all keys defined in the menu, let them go, and ignore everything else? In other words: do I have to manually list all the menu shortcuts either in the subclass or in eventFilter, or is there a way to pull the automatically from menu definition?

Comment: I do not think you could easily read out the combinations defined, but eventually you could use ``QKeyEvent::text().size() > 0 && QKeyEvent::modifiers != Qt::NoModifier``. I think ``text()`` only shows the resulting text, but i will have to test this. But generally reimplementing the event gets bigger then initially planned, at least this happened always to us

Comment: So just to check if I understood: if that above trick wouldn't work (I will try it, though!), one has to remember which shortcuts the application uses (A=Select All, X=Cut, Z=Undo, ...) and then in the subclass or evenFilter manually check whether the event key was one of A, X, Z, ... and reject everything else. Is this correct? Because, you know, then I have to type it twice and if I add shortcut to the application and forget to change the subclass then it will break...

Comment: Unfortunately that trick doesn't work: it does not distinguishes between already set shortcuts and non-set ones...

Comment: You could also try calling the original event of the super class and then check the resulting document for modifications.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you said: you mean to try to execute the commands twice? And if there was a modification then what? Call undo?

Comment: Kind of. Save a copy of your document, call QTextEdit::keyPressEvent(e), check for modification on QTextDocument::plainText() and do perform an undo if needed. This is quite the dirty way, but it would eventually fit your demands.

Comment: @TuomL. You can actually check for known shortcuts using: ``QList<QKeySequence> QKeySequence::keyBindings ( StandardKey key )``. Never used it though, just found it by coincidence. This makes it possible to just forwards events in the returned QList and throw away the rest.

Comment: That looks good but how to get `StandardKey` from the key event?

Comment: ``QKeyEvent* e; if (e == QKeySequence::Copy){ /* do sth. */ }``

Comment: Yes, but that's exactly the problem I have: I don't want to manually check for all the `QKeySequence::Copy`, `QKeySequence::Cut`, ... defined in menu.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to create a QKeySequence from your given data (Key + Modifiers) and call QKeySequence::keyBindings. If this QList has entries a binding exists.

Comment: The problem is, that `::keyBindings` require this "StandardKey", and I couldn't find a way which doesn't end with the error: "no viable conversion from 'QKeySequence' to 'QKeySequence::StandardKey'". Hey, but thanks a lot for all the tips!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

CSimpleEdit.h

```
#include <QPlainTextEdit>
class CSimpleEdit: public QPlainTextEdit
{ Q_OBJECT
  public:
    explicit      CSimpleEdit(QWidget* parent = 0);
    ~             CSimpleEdit();
  protected:
    bool          eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* event);
};
```

CSimpleEdit.cpp

```
CSimpleEdit::CSimpleEdit(QWidget* parent)
  : QPlainTextEdit(parent)
{ installEventFilter(this); }

CSimpleEdit::~CSimpleEdit()
{ removeEventFilter(this); }

bool CSimpleEdit::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
  if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
  { QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
    if (keyEvent->modifiers() != Qt::NoModifier &&
        !keyEvent->modifiers().testFlag(Qt::ShiftModifier))
    { bool bMatch = false;
      for (int i = QKeySequence::HelpContents; i < QKeySequence::Deselect; i++)
      { bMatch = keyEvent->matches((QKeySequence::StandardKey) i);
        if (bMatch) break;
      }
      /*You can also set bMatch to true by checking you application
       *actions list -> QWidget::actions(). */
      if (!bMatch) return true;
    }
  }
  else if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyRelease)
  { QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
    if (keyEvent->modifiers() != Qt::NoModifier &&
        !keyEvent->modifiers().testFlag(Qt::ShiftModifier))
    { bool bMatch = false;
      for (int i = QKeySequence::HelpContents; i < QKeySequence::Deselect; i++)
      { bMatch = keyEvent->matches((QKeySequence::StandardKey) i);
        if (bMatch) break;
      }
      if (!bMatch) return true;
    }
  }
  return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

Comment: I'm using 5.1, too. Just to check - in the above code you didn't alter QPlainTextEdit in any way, right? Because it does not work, i.e. the ctrl+j **does** show up.

Comment: Well, I'm using it in Ubunt 13.04, Windows 8 (vc2012) and Mac OS X Snow Leopard, but they behave the same way. I've checked it and ALT+<Key> shows up, but CTRL+<Any Other> does not; ALT+<Key> shows if the key combination is no set as an action shortcut or menu/buddy access. But I'll try to build a solution for you as long as you can process only keypresses, but not keyboard modifiers.